# Python - xarray mean between two netcdf files

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have yearly nc files, and each one  of them contain daily min and max temperature data.

What I want to do, is to obtain the average temperature with those two variables.

I thought that with xarray would be easier, I've managed to merge all files into one like this:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import xarray

tmin = xarray.open_mfdataset('TMIN*.nc',combine = 'by_coords', concat_dim="time")


tmax = xarray.open_mfdataset('TMAX*.nc',combine = 'by_coords', concat_dim="time")
```

Then, I tried to do something like: `tavg = (tmax - tmin) / 2`

But I got an empty array (shown below):

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 294, lon: 402, time: 25567)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 11.9125 11.995833 12.079166 ... 36.245834 36.329166
  * lon      (lon) float32 -119.4375 -119.354164 ... -86.104164 -86.020836
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-01-01 1950-01-02 ... 2019-12-31
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

How can I get the mean between the two variables for each day?

As suggested, here are the summaries for both tmin and tmax:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 294, lon: 402, time: 25567)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 -119.4375 -119.354164 ... -86.104164 -86.020836
  * lat      (lat) float32 11.9125 11.995833 12.079166 ... 36.245834 36.329166
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-01-01 1950-01-02 ... 2019-12-31
Data variables:
    TMAX     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(365, 294, 402), meta=np.ndarray>


<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 294, lon: 402, time: 25567)
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float32 -119.4375 -119.354164 ... -86.104164 -86.020836
  * lat      (lat) float32 11.9125 11.995833 12.079166 ... 36.245834 36.329166
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1950-01-01 1950-01-02 ... 2019-12-31
Data variables:
    TMIN     (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(365, 294, 402), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Comment: Taking a step back for a moment before we dive into the technical solution here... if you are wanting the average temperature, are you sure that you want the average of min and max? Most data sources which would provide daily min and max (whether it is observed or modelled temperature) will probably also have a daily mean product available also. What is this data, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes that would be a better option. The thing is I'm working with stations and they only register the tmin and tmax for each day (I don't know why but that's what they do). I'm aware that it may not be the best approach but it's the best I can do.

Comment: Okay, fair enough -- just thought I'd check.

Comment: Have you checked that the `tmin` and `tmax` datasets do indeed contain data (though you may run into lazy data loading; use `tm??.load()` to avoid that if necessary). It would be good to include the summary of `tmin` or `tmax` in your question, similar as you have done for `tavg`.

Comment: Yes, both of them contain data. I've added the summaries for both of them.

Comment: I didn't know about xarray unttil this post. Did you try with pandas?

Comment: @aerijman These data are not in a CSV file or similar format: .nc, NetCDF, is a specialized binary format, often used in climate science, and xarray is a package for reading and handling such files. Internally, once read, the data is handled in NumPy arrays (with a wrapper that keeps track of other things), hence it is possible to perform operations like `(tmax - tmin)/2`. Pandas will not help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that Tmin and Tmax are datasets and not dataarrays.

If you try to add the two datasets together xarray does not know how to add the variables inside the dataset together. After all you can have multiple variables in one dataset.

To solve this you simply select the variables inside the datasets you would like to add.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

lon = np.arange(129.4, 153.75+0.05, 0.25)
lat = np.arange(-43.75, -10.1+0.05, 0.25)

Tmin = 10 * np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))
Tmax = 10 * np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))


Tmin = xr.Dataset({"Tmin": (["lat", "lon"], Tmin)},coords={"lon": lon,"lat": lat})
Tmax = xr.Dataset({"Tmax": (["lat", "lon"], Tmax)},coords={"lon": lon,"lat": lat})

# Just checking the datasets are not empty
print(Tmin)
print(Tmax)

# This will return an empty array as per your example 
tavg = (Tmax+Tmin)/2
print(tavg)

# Selecting the variable should work
tavg = (Tmax['Tmax']+Tmin['Tmin'])/2
print(tavg)
```